# Windows Store app package upload - Internal package processing error

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

My Windows Store app is built and deployed successfully on test machines. It is successfully validated from Windows App Certification Kit (WACK) with all the tests enabled. But when I try to upload it to the Windows Store, I always get the following error stack trace during the upload step of the submission process:

> Internal package processing error: System.ArgumentException: Invalid OsMinVersion: 0 at Microsoft.MarketplaceServices.Ingestion.ProductCatalogService.Controllers.V1.PackageValidationV1Controller.WindowsMinVersionsAreSameOsVersion(Int64 osMinVersion, Int64 osMinVersion2) in c:\B\311\DCEProductCatalog_Live\S\private\DCEProductCatalog\src\ProductCatalogFD\ProductCatalogFD\V1\Global\PackageValidationV1Controller.cs:line 3249 at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) at Microsoft.MarketplaceServices.Ingestion.ProductCatalogService.Controllers.V1.PackageValidationV1Controller.d__1c6.MoveNext() in c:\B\311\DCEProductCatalog_Live\S\private\DCEProductCatalog\src\ProductCatalogFD\ProductCatalogFD\V1\Global\PackageValidationV1Controller.cs:line 3211 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.MarketplaceServices.Ingestion.ProductCatalogService.Controllers.V1.PackageValidationV1Controller.d__12b.MoveNext() in c:\B\311\DCEProductCatalog_Live\S\private\DCEProductCatalog\src\ProductCatalogFD\ProductCatalogFD\V1\Global\PackageValidationV1Controller.cs:line 2335 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.MarketplaceServices.Ingestion.ProductCatalogService.Controllers.V1.PackageValidationV1Controller.d__db.MoveNext() in c:\B\311\DCEProductCatalog_Live\S\private\DCEProductCatalog\src\ProductCatalogFD\ProductCatalogFD\V1\Global\PackageValidationV1Controller.cs:line 1746 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.MarketplaceServices.Ingestion.ProductCatalogService.Controllers.V1.PackageValidationV1Controller.d__68.MoveNext() in c:\B\311\DCEProductCatalog_Live\S\private\DCEProductCatalog\src\ProductCatalogFD\ProductCatalogFD\V1\Global\PackageValidationV1Controller.cs:line 851 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.MarketplaceServices.Ingestion.ProductCatalogService.Controllers.V1.PackageValidationV1Controller.d__40.MoveNext() in c:\B\311\DCEProductCatalog_Live\S\private\DCEProductCatalog\src\ProductCatalogFD\ProductCatalogFD\V1\Global\PackageValidationV1Controller.cs:line 551 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.MarketplaceServices.Ingestion.ProductCatalogService.Controllers.V1.PackageValidationV1Controller.d__0.MoveNext() in c:\B\311\DCEProductCatalog_Live\S\private\DCEProductCatalog\src\ProductCatalogFD\ProductCatalogFD\V1\Global\PackageValidationV1Controller.cs:line 242

This is my first submission to the Windows Store ever and it's quite strange for me that I can even see the stack trace instead of a user friendly error message.
As far as I understood, users usually receive a helpful error message with a "How to fix it" section.

I have already contacted Microsoft support and they weren't able to help me. They only suggested asking in their technical forum, as I already did, but I haven't received any answer so far and my deadline is coming.

Any idea why I see this error?

UPDATE: I found people with similar problems whose accounts were migrated to the new unified Windows Development dashboard exactly like mine. So it might be a problem in the new submission and validation process.

Comment: `OSMinVersion` is specified inside of an xml file in your project - "Package.appxmanifest". Use a *text editor* to view that file and search for the XML node `OSMinVersion`. What do you see inside of the node? In my app I have `<OSMinVersion>6.3.0</OSMinVersion>`, which targets Win 8.1. I also have `<OSMaxVersionTested>6.3.0</OSMaxVersionTested>` in the next node.

Comment: @chuex Yes, I know that I have to specify this in the app manifest, I have both values there. I am pretty sure that if the OSMinVersion is not specified, It will be detected by the WACK, and the test will fail.

Comment: I would try creating a new project and comparing the app manifest from that one with your project. Maybe you will find something in that process. Otherwise it does really sound like an issue in the App Store submission code.